# Istio tracing tying multiple requests together using header

Tags: istio, jaeger

I am using Istio with tracing.  I have two REST services A1 which calls A2.
The A1 service will forward the headers received from the client to REST service A2.

However, I am not able to see the tracing in my Jaeger UI.  I am sending some random values in the header using curl to my service A1:

```
 curl -H "end-user: april1101" -H "x-request-id: april1a01" 
   -H "x-b3-traceid: 1" -H "x-b3-spanid: 2" -H "x-b3-parentspanid: 3"
   -H "x-b3-sampled: 4dfgdgsdfgdfg" -H "x-b3-flags: 5" 
   -H "x-ot-span-context: 6"  http://trace-rest-2-service:9005/kafka/headerpass?arg=yo
```

Another header parameters I tried also is:

```
curl -H "end-user: 34723b86-fe18-4e36-ac56-0ad12bf3d136" 
-H "x-request-id: 4aba321a-4e60-4b42-b0ca-654c2400d485" 
-H "x-b3-traceid: 308eec41-93bd-4584-8efe-2b968284c41e" 
-H "x-b3-spanid: 8395e40e-6a79-4a34-b444-18d401f597cb" 
-H "x-b3-parentspanid: c55f6cf0-3547-4202-b51e-9eaaa2136a73" 
-H "x-b3-sampled: 1948dd81-9e70-4694-95f9-018e3abdbe29" 
-H "x-b3-flags: acac5baf-42d2-45d8-84d0-645070a76f2e" 
-H "x-ot-span-context: 6ee27e27-45c4-47de-86e4-1d4227bcf638"  
http://trace-rest-2-service:9005/kafka/headerpass?arg=832amApril_1
```

However, I don't see any trace on Jaeger ui.  If just call a service A3 without passing any headers then I see that traced in the JaegerUI.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different reasons why You could be experiencing this issue.

From [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-sampling) documentation:

> WHY ARE MY REQUESTS NOT BEING TRACED?
>
> Since Istio 1.0.3, the sampling rate for tracing has been reduced to 1% in the  `default`  [configuration profile](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/). This means that only 1 out of 100 trace instances captured by Istio will be reported to the tracing backend. The sampling rate in the  `demo`  profile is still set to 100%. See  [this section](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-sampling)  for more information on how to set the sampling rate.
>
> If you still do not see any trace data, please confirm that your ports conform to the Istio  [port naming conventions](https://istio.io/faq/traffic-management/#naming-port-convention)  and that the appropriate container port is exposed (via pod spec, for example) to enable traffic capture by the sidecar proxy (Envoy).
>
> If you only see trace data associated with the egress proxy, but not the ingress proxy, it may still be related to the Istio  [port naming conventions](https://istio.io/faq/traffic-management/#naming-port-convention). Starting with  [Istio 1.3](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.3.x/announcing-1.3/#intelligent-protocol-detection-experimental)  the protocol for  **outbound**  traffic is automatically detected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can see one or two traces that hit only 1 service but not the ones where I curl and call service A (header propagated) which calls service B.

Comment: What is the value of Your trace sampling? Information how to do that is [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-sampling).

Comment: I am passing the following in my curl statement.  These are all UUIDs that I generated in java.  I am going to paste my other curl statement above in my question.